# Unsuccessfully assigning to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I only ask this question because I have isolated it to pretty much three lines of code, so it's probably something really obvious that I just screwed up because I'm inexperienced:

```
Movie* ptr;
if(title == r->getItem().getTitle())
{
    ptr = &(r->getItem());
    cout << "Found: " << ptr->getTitle() << "!";
}
```

Essentially whats going on is that `title == "The Godfather"` so therefore that's what
 `r->getItem().getTitle()` is returning. What I don't understand though, is that when I try to make a pointer that points to the `Movie` object returned by `r.getItem()`, I can't use the pointer. It definitely had *something* assigned to it, but when I try to do `ptr->getTitle()` its returning null.

What on earth is going on?

Comment: This is not enough code. we don't even know the types of anything in there other than `ptr`.

Comment: Can you tell use what `r` points to, and what `r->GetItem()` returns?

Comment: `title == "The Godfather` seems like you should be using an actual string comparison and not a pointer one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing something like this

```
Movie& getItem () {
   Movie m ();
   return m;
}

/* ... */

Movie * p = & (getItem ());
```

The problem is that m is a stack object which gets lost after getItem has returned. That's a common mistake in C++.

The getTitle call should not work either, but it might by chance.

You must create the object on the heap.

My simple rule to avoid this: Don't use the & operator altogether unless you haven't thought about what you are doing ten times.

Answer (score 0):

You should post more code. But most probably `getItem` returns you an object **by value**, i.e. it returns a *temporary* object, which is a copy of the original one. After the assignment - this temporary object is destroyed, so your `ptr` points to a destroyed object, (potentially) inaccessible mempory.

Answer (score 0):

A number of things could be happening here:

1. The getItem() method may not return a Movie class directly, what is the definition of the method? It could be an inherited class where getTitle() is implemented differently.
2. It may return a reference to a class which then goes out of scope, causing a memory error.
3. The getTitle() method may not return something you can stream, is it really a string? What's the definition of that method?